# Java Regex Issue when regex is correct

Tags: java, regex

I have a regex that is correct, yet it fails in my program. Often a different set of eyes is good.

Relevant Code:

```
String s_mapping = ".*<MAPPING DESCRIPTION.*NAME =.*";
Pattern mapName = Pattern.compile("\"(m_.*?)\"");
String o_mapping = "";

...

if (line.matches(s_mapping)){
                Matcher matcher = mapName.matcher(line);
                System.out.println(line);
                System.out.println(matcher);
                o_mapping = matcher.group(1);
                System.out.println(o_mapping);
```

Output

```
<MAPPING DESCRIPTION ="Mapping to generate the parameters file based on the parameters inserted in the table." ISVALID ="YES" NAME ="m_FAR_Gen_ParmFile" OBJECTVERSION ="1" VERSIONNUMBER ="2">
java.util.regex.Matcher[pattern="(m_.*?)" region=0,195 lastmatch=]
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match found
```

I expect to finally see `m_FAR_Gen_ParmFile` as my o_mapping output.

When I test at this site: http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html, All passes and all is well.  Why does it fail in my program? and how do I fix it?

Comment: We can't reproduce this without knowing `line`. Please show a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem - and explain what you expected to see vs what you actually saw.

Comment: I have given you `line` check the output. If you follow my SysOuts, you have everything relevant

Comment: @staples I don't see it. Mind posting it as part of the code ?

Comment: @staples: Ah... that wasn't clear, and reading a question shouldn't be a detective story in itself. Why not just produce a short but complete program we can run?

Comment: Sorry about being unclear. -- where is a good place I could produce a short complete program online to post?

Comment: @staples: You would "produce" it on your machine, just as a console app - then include it in the question. It would only need to be about 10 lines long in this case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to call `find()` before `group()`:

```
if (line.matches(s_mapping)){
    Matcher matcher = mapName.matcher(line);
    System.out.println(line);
    System.out.println(matcher);
    matcher.find();
    o_mapping = matcher.group(1);
    System.out.println(o_mapping);
```

From the [`Matcher#group()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group(int)) Javadoc:

> *Throws:
>
>   **IllegalStateException** - If no match has yet been attempted, or if the previous match operation failed*